# Form filling and automatic submission using cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm working on having ability to automatically log in on demand to my clients account and download a given document. as the first step of trying to login i'm working with the following code

```
<?php

$post_data=array();

$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 

//create cURL connection
//this is just sample login url to have a session with the server
//this first access is to allow me get the hidden fields in the page
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://www.facebook.com');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
$result=htmlspecialchars($result);
/* str_replace("<","&lt",$result);
str_replace(">","&gt",$result); */
/* echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>"; */
$body_array=explode("&lt;input",$result);
/* echo "<pre>";
print_r($body_array);
echo "</pre>"; */
    foreach($body_array as $key =>$value)
    {

        $element_array1=explode('&gt;',$value);
        echo "<pre>";
    //  print_r($element_array1);
        echo "</pre>";  
        if (strpos(strtolower($element_array1[0]), 'hidden') !== false) {
            $we_have_hidden_array=explode('hidden',($element_array1[0]));

            foreach($we_have_hidden_array as $hae)
                {
                    $hae_wna= explode("name=",strstr(str_replace("&#39;",'&quot;',$hae),"name="));
                    $hae_wna=array_values(array_filter($hae_wna));
                    if(count($hae_wna) > 0)
                    {
                    $first_wna = explode(' ',$hae_wna[0]);
                    $final_keys=str_replace('&quot;'," ",$first_wna[0]);
                    $final_key_array=explode(" ",$final_keys);
                    $final_key_array=array_values(array_filter($final_key_array));
                    $final_key=$final_key_array[0];
                    $post_data[$final_key]=0;
                    }

                    $hae_wna= explode("value=",strstr(str_replace("&#39;",'&quot;',$hae),"value="));
                    $hae_wna=array_values(array_filter($hae_wna));
                    if(count($hae_wna) > 0)
                    {

                    $first_wna = explode(' ',$hae_wna[0]);

                    $final_values=str_replace('&quot;'," ",$first_wna[0]);
                    $final_value_array=explode(" ",$final_values);
                    $final_value_array=array_values(array_filter($final_value_array));
                    $final_value=$final_value_array[0];
                    $post_data[$final_key]=$final_value;
                    }

                }
        }
    }


//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['username'] = 'admin';
$post_data['passwd'] = 'admin';



//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
 print_r($post_data);
//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
//this is just sample login
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://www.facebook.com');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
echo $result;
//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_getinfo($curl_connection, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);

?>
```

My Problem is that I cant find the code to work, getting status 200 and thats just it.... what could be the thing that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: And you have to login to your clients Facebook?

Comment: Thats just a sample url. Sorry if its misleading. Can you then address the question?